# IReport: span a long table over multiples pages

Tags: ireport

I need to span a long table over multiples pages horizontally. is there a Text_field "Strecth with overflow"-attribute like for table component ?

Comment: I just figured out the trick,the (my..!) rule is: for multiples independents tables with different length, "USE ONE DETAIL BAND BY TABLE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the trick,the (my..!) rule is: for multiples independents tables with different length, "USE ONE DETAIL BAND BY TABLE"